# Podio Field is empty but the flow runs in globiflow

Tags: automation, podio

The flow keeps on running and commenting even if the field does not match the filter i have applied to the flow. It is running even if i enter any other thing in the field or keep it empty.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the first OR to an AND. The reason it is executing every time is that your current filter is saying "if the MSA field value changes OR is equal to Tampa OR Orlando OR Jacksonville". Instead, it needs to say "if the MSA field value changes AND is equal to Tampa OR Orlando OR Jacksonville". This will result in the field being required to be changed as well as equaling either Tampa, Orlando or Jacksonville.

Comment: Yeah I was also searching for the answer and found the exact problem and changed it. Thank you, I appreciate!